# Switch statement passing in id of button not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use a switch statement `switch (buttionId)`, passing in the id of the button that I am selecting, however, the function is not firing properly.  Here is my function:

```
function PickDiagCode(btnNum, button) {
        var txtID;
        var strId;
        //var buttonId = $("input[id*=btnHeaderDiagPick]").attr("id");
        switch (button.value) {
            case "Clear":
                switch (button.id) {                    
                        case "btnHeaderDiagPick1":
                           //Do Work

                        case "btnHeaderDiagPick2":
                           //Do Work
```

Here are the buttons:

```
    <input class="Button-Search" id="btnHeaderDiagPick1" onclick="document.frmCrgEntry.hdnPickClrDiagCode.value='1';PickDiagCode('1',btnHeaderDiagPick1);"
                                    type="button" name="btnHeaderDiagPick1" runat="server" />
    <input class="Button-Search" id="btnHeaderDiagPick2" onclick="document.frmCrgEntry.hdnPickClrDiagCode.value='2';PickDiagCode(2,btnHeaderDiagPick2);"
                                type="button" name="btnHeaderDiagPick2" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, it should always enter the first case `btnHeaderDiagPick1` assuming `btnID.value` always returns `"Clear"`

Comment: So you're using jQuery, and *not* binding events from JavaScript? Good luck maintaining that code, it'll be a nightmare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `document.getElementById()`

```
switch (btnID.value) {
```

change to

```
switch (document.getElementById(btnID).value) {
```

Comment: we don't know what `btnID` is, in his html it's referencing a global variable that may or may not exist (that may be where the real problem is)

Comment: @KevinB True. I made the assumption the variable btnID is a string and not the element itself.

Comment: I btnID is the element.  I am trying to pass the id property of the element.  The value is returning as the text of the element.

Comment: @MTL323 I don't understand you at all. If the variable is an `element`, then don't affix `id` to the end, which would indicate it is a `string`.

Comment: I apologize for the misunderstanding, I am new to javascript and still need a better understanding on how to construct functions properly. I edited the original function above.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be this:

```
document.frmCrgEntry.hdnPickClrDiagCode.value='1';
```

If you remove it everything works just fine. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3aWYa/17/) where one button has it, and one doesn't. The button where it is removed, works without issue (for calling the function)